# changing classname within if statement has no visual effect yet the property changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, classname

I have simple html+javascript screen where there are buttons attached to the screen at runtime
It used to work in IE6, but now the platform updated to windows 7 + IE9 (in IE8 comp mode) and the screen is all scrambled up.

This is part of that function

```
function AttachButton(btn, buttonloc)
{
    var elTr = document.createElement('TR');
    var elTdText = document.createElement('TD');
    elTdText.id= idbase+"text";

    elTr.appendChild(elTdText);
    //*snip*
    //here was code that attaches the TR to the proper table
    //******
    if (elTdText.offsetWidth < 162 && btnText.search("<br>") < 0) {
        elTdText.className = "singlebutton";
    }
    else {
        elTdText.className = "doublebutton";
    }
    if (btn.name == "contact") {
        elTdText.className = "contactbutton";
    }
}
```

This seems to have no effect. The page has the same style if I delete this part of the code.
But whenever I add className=className at the end of this function, all is working fine again
like this:

```
function AttachButton(btn, buttonloc)
{
    var elTr = document.createElement('TR');
    var elTdText = document.createElement('TD');
    elTdText.id= idbase+"text";

    elTr.appendChild(elTdText);
    //*snip*
    //here was code that attaches the TR to the proper table
    //******
    if (elTdText.offsetWidth < 162 && btnText.search("<br>") < 0) {
        elTdText.className = "singlebutton";
    }
    else {
        elTdText.className = "doublebutton";
    }
    if (btn.name == "contact") {
        elTdText.className = "contactbutton";
    }
    elTdText.className = elTdText.className;
}
```

I tried changing the code to use setAttribute("class", "singlebutton") or storing className in a string and use elTdText.className = classNameVar but to no effect.
Unless i add the stupid looking className = className, it does not work.

Comment: what happens in other browsers?  Is this a problem with your code or with IE?

Comment: I guess you're changing the background (color) of `tr`, which is covered by a background of a `td`. But still I can't imagine any affect when doing `elTdText.className = elTdText.className;`. Can we see the relevant CSS?

Comment: I can't test it on another browser. It is used like a kind of kiosk and there is too much IE specific (legacy) code in there

Comment: maybe i should describe what is wrong. That class does nothing but position and style text. Whithout the code, the text is next to the image it is supposed to be on top of. Those classnames set color, height, wordwrap, top, left, postion, zindex and fontfamily. the main change is setting the position to abosulte i think

Comment: I see, in some point of version developement, setting `position: absolute` for an element in `td` uses `table` as a positioned parent, older versions used `td`, i.e. absolute positioning inside `td` is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, className is IE-specific. Try using "class" or `setAttribute('class', ...)`

**EDIT** since you tried, the error is probably because of :

```
elTdText.className = elTdText.className;
```

A = A does nothing.

Comment: What?! `className` is very all-browser-specific property name.

Comment: It's time to extend [the knowledge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) ; ).

Comment: Maybe you should read my problem again. I know it is a stupid line of code but unless the A=A is there, it isn't working. Yet, the property is correct when I do an alert of it right before that line

Comment: Well i can read it over and over, i will never understand why you would do `elTdText.className = elTdText.className;` and why doing this would change anything. :o

Comment: @Teemu If member names no longer match attribute names (i.e id -> id, class -> className), then it is no longer consistent, may leader to errors and unintuitive code etc, and should no longer be used.

Comment: That specific property name has been like this from DOM level 2, didn't you read the article? Though you're right about `elTdText.className = elTdText.className;`, it really doesn't change anything.

Comment: i know. I had been looking at the issue for some while and I accidentally put that like of code there. I hate it when I can't explain stuff :(